# How do I obtain the number of days within a given month using Joda-Time?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

```
30 days hath September,
   April, June and November,
 All the rest have 31,
   Excepting February alone
(And that has 28 days clear,
   With 29 in each leap year).
```

Can I obtain this info anagrammatically?
(I don't mean the poem, of course)

Comment: Hmmm... anagramatically, or programmatically?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

If you have a `DateTime` object which represents a value in the month, then it's pretty straightforward.  You get the `dayOfMonth` property from that `DateTime` object and get the maximum value of the property.  Here is a sample function:

```java
public static int daysOfMonth(int year, int month) {
  DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(year, month, 14, 12, 0, 0, 000);
  return dateTime.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue();
}
```

Comment: This didn't  work for me.  getMaximumValue() returns 31 for November, which is of course not correct.

Comment: @ChrisGerken: Maybe your months are zero-indexed?  For JODA, the month should be a value from 1-12.  If you used 10 for November, JODA would see that as October and return 31.

Comment: Nearly all of my date related bugs are because JODA is not zero indexed. It is tough to remember!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, although it's not as pretty as it might be:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.chrono.*;
import org.joda.time.field.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GregorianChronology calendar = GregorianChronology.getInstance();
        DateTimeField field = calendar.dayOfMonth();

        for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
            LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2010, i, 1, calendar);
            System.out.println(field.getMaximumValue(date));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've hard-coded the assumption that there are 12 months, and that we're interested in 2010. I've *explicitly* selected the Gregorian chronology though - in other chronologies you'd get different answers, of course. (And the "12 month" loop wouldn't be a valid assumption either...)

I've gone for a `LocalDate` rather than a `DateTime` in order to fetch the value, to emphasize (however faintly :) that the value doesn't depend on the time zone.

This is still not as simple as it looks, mind you. I don't know off-hand what happens if use one chronology to construct the `LocalDate`, but ask for the maximum value of a field in a different chronology. I have some ideas about what *might* happen, knowing a certain amount about Joda Time, but it's probably not a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, yourMonth);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, yourYear);
cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // <-- the result!
```

Comment: That's not Jodatime. The OP explicitly asked for this.

Comment: Oups. Exact... I focused on the problem and forgot the title... But if the result can be obtained easily with the standard API, an external API like JodaTime is useless.

Comment: I would personally stay *well* away from java.util.Calendar. Joda Time is a far, far superior API. For example, how confident are you about what that will do if you set it to February when `getInstance` returns the 31st of September? Oh, and don't forget that February is month 1...

Comment: I hear you about external API's, but Java's Calendar package is a known liability.  Joda slides right in with no problems.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another simple function:

```
int daysOfMonth(DateTime dt) {
    int month = dt.getMonthOfYear();
    int month2 = month;
    int days = dt.getDay();
    DateTime dt2 = dt;
    while (month == month2 ) {
       days++;
       dt2.addDays(1);
       month2 = dt2.getMonthOfYear();
    }
    return (days - 1);
}
```